# PHP to have required text fields

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, validation

I have created a simple form that currently submits to a database. I am now wanting to add validation so that each field is required to be filled in.

This is what i have so far:

```
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
</br>
<form method = "post" action = "post-poster.php">
<label>Address Line 1:</label> <input name="addline1" id="addline1"></br>
<label>Area:</label> <input name="area" id="area"></br>
<label>Description:</label> <input name="description" id="description"></br>
<label>Bedrooms: </label><input name="bedrooms" id="bedrooms"></br>
<label>Bathrooms:</label> <input name="bathrooms" id="bathrooms"></br>
<label>Landlords Name:</label> <input name="lname" id="lname"></br>
<label>Landlords Number:</label> <input name="lphone" id="lphone"></br>
<label>Landlords Email:</label> <input name="lemail" id="lemail"></br>
</br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

and this is the file that submits to the DB, i have blanked my db details:

```
<?php
/*
Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password)
*/
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "inspire_****", "*****", "inspire_****");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$addline1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['addline1']);
$area = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['area']);
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['description']);
$bedrooms = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['bedrooms']);
$bathrooms = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['bathrooms']);
$lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['lname']);
$lphone = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['lphone']);
$lemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['lemail']);


// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO posts (addline1, area, description, bedrooms, bathrooms, lname, lphone, lemail) VALUES ('$addline1', '$area', '$description', '$bedrooms', '$bathrooms', '$lname', '$lphone', '$lemail')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

If anyone can help me i would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The easy way is to add `required` to each `input` tag.

Comment: Are you aiming to do a client side validation or a server side one or both ? For client side, try the jQuery validation.

Comment: at least try someting

Comment: @MattCremeens hi mat, thanks for the comment what do you mean by adding required to each input tag?

Comment: Use `if(empty($_POST['addline1'])) { // complain about required field }`

Comment: @stephenaxe18 `<input name="addline1" id="addline1" required>`

Comment: @stephenaxe18 please see my answer below.

Comment: @Barmar thanks that works great for what I want thank you!

Comment: I think Barmar's suggestion for server side validation should do the trick, but you could even consider adding constraints to the table, so you can't insert empty values there. By doing so, the insert will fail, which you can check for in your code, and display an error message accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way, perhaps the lazy way, is to add `required` to each `input` tag. For example

```
<input name="addline1" id="addline1" required>
```

You can add the key word `required` in this manner to all `input` tags that apply.

Comment: Client side validation. Useful, but not enough. The server side script should *always* validate the input. The client side stuff is just for a better UX.

Comment: I can appreciate this answer and believe you know what you are talking about, but it would be useful to know why it's not enough to prevent the user from submitting a form when certain fields are not filled in.

Comment: @MattCremeens Because it is simple to circumvent client-side validation.

Comment: Not all browsers may support this 'required' attribute (although in practice they all do), and one might even change the HTML, or post the data using some other tool than a browser. In that case, you want to make sure that the server doesn't fail in a very awkward way. In this case, awkward means that the empty values would still be inserted.

Comment: @Golez You are correct. Client-side validation is good because it is convenient for the user (no HTTP requests need to be made in order to determine that the input is invalid). However, users can easily bypass client-side validation (disabling JavaScript or modifying the code). So server-side validation is always a ***must***.

Comment: @GolezTrol that is a helpful explanation. Thank you.